# Scrollable div inside a table

Tags: html, html-table, scrollbar, overflow

I need to place a scrollable div in a table cell. The table should be 100% height. The div has a lot of content that doesn't fit in the screen so scrolling should appear. But I want only the **div** to be scrollable, not the whole page.
If I don't use table, everything is perfect:

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100px; padding: 5px; overflow: auto; border-width: 1px;  border-style: solid;">
    <div>
       Item 1<br/>
       Item 2<br/>
       ...
       Item 300<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div is scrollable, page has no scrollbar. But if it's wrapped in a table:

```
<table style="height: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height: 100%; width: 100px; padding: 5px; overflow: auto; border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;">
                <div>
                   Item 1<br/>
                   Item 2<br/>
                   ...
                   Item 300<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

page becomes scrollable, and the div ceases to be such. What can I do?

Comment: I must ask why you are using tables for layout. If there is actual data in the cells this might be okay. Keep in mind that tables are not designed for layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary to use tables in my case. I need to fix very complicated layout written rather long ago. It is hard to remake it.

Comment: Yours code ( with table) works fine in IE8 and chrome. Are you sure that this sample didnt work for you?

Comment: It is needed to work in Firefox, but it doesn't. I haven't tested it in other browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be `height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;` on `<td>` ?

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't change anything. Found that if I make height: 100%; and overflow: auto; on <tbody>, tbody becomes scrollable. But this is not what I need... I need to scroll div or td.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you cannot expect the div to go to 100% height, because the table that is holding it also has a % as its width.

The container of the div must have an absolute height.

This is my code:

```
<table height="2000px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height: 100%; width: 100px; padding: 5px; overflow: scroll; border: 1px solid #000;">
                Item 1<br/>
                Item 2<br/>
                ...<br/>
                Item 300<br/>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which uses a scroll bar on the div and because of its height also makes the page scroll bar appear.

Unforunately unless you use some hacky CSS work around (Which might won't work in all browsers) you cannot tell a div to be 100% height without giving its container an absolute height as I have done above.

If I am wrong I'm sure someone will correct me, but I have tried to give divs 100% height to fit the browser window in the past without CSS or Javascript hacks and failed.

Comment: Thanks. I can't use fixed height in this case, unfortunately. If I don't find the answer I will think about using JS for the table to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Tables actually use minimum height, so whenever your div gets bigger than what you want, the table column is actually just resizing to fit your div, and so your div percentage is rendered useless.

You need to use divs, not tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should change table-layout css property to "fixed" value.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow: scroll;">
                Scrollable div
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A good thing is to explain why adding `table-layout: fixed` is the best thing to do here.

Comment: As [w3schools says](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) fixed table layout algorithm means that
"*The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells*"

Comment: would be nice to see that paragraph included in your answer.  That was the only thing I wanted to point out.